# Use Google Keep as default notes services on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome-extensions

I noticed that in Windows 10 you are able to set some kind of app for notes. By default this is Microsoft's OneNote.

[image: Sorry for uploading a picture instead of a screenshot, I wasn't able to screenshot this part of the screen.]

However I am not a big fan of OneNote so I would like to configure it to work with Google Keep. I tried searching for this in Default Programs but no luck there.

Is this possible to do and if so how?

Comment: This likely isn't possible (currently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\onenote-cmd\shell\Open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" https://keep.google.com/"
```

The above registry edit should work for keep+firefox. It does for me, at least, although I registered it on HKEY_USERS too, just to be on the safe side (but I have no idea how to know the user registry ID without being in front of it)

you can also pretend you have an app by installing google chrome, the google keep extension, and open it as a "standalone" app. The url looks something like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki`

Answer (score 2):

Google keep cannot serve as a default program, because it's a google chrome extension and not registered as a program at windows, but you can create shortcuts to your desktop or start menu to use it.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/9jHS2dpJX5Q

Answer (score 1):

There's a windows store app called EasyNotes for Keep. Haven't tried it much but seems like that's the closest we can get for now.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/easynotes-for-keep/9nblggh68pn5

Comment: Welcome to superuser, the question was now to "Use Google Keep as default notes services on Windows 10" while your answer may well work and be correct it is best suited as a comment.

Comment: @mic84 Thanks for the comment. I understand this should have been a comment but unfortunately I do not have a reputation score of 50+ to do that. As I thought my answer would be of some value, I posted it as an answer instead,

Comment: This app is only embedding web version and shows ads. Absolutely not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Go to setting, choose system, click default apps, click set defaults by app.
Select the program that you want to use for default then you can choose how the program will act, as a default program or choose default for this program.

Comment: Google Keep doesn't show up in that menu.

Comment: Not applicable.